# JQuery Stop Animation Queue

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

my aim is change and animate an element (in the case a `<h2>` and `<p>`) on the hover of another element (a `<div>`), to return to it's prior state when un-hovered and for the animation to stop when hovered on another (`<div>`) element.

I've achieved changing the contents and animating them using JQuery `.hover` but I can't stop the animations queuing up when hovering on multiple `<div>`'s quickly.

I've tried using the `.stop()` function (both `.stop(true, false);` and `.stop(true, true);`) I'm sure this is something I'm doing wrong, but I just can't wrap my head round it.

Here is an example Codepen, I've added some comments to make it cleat what is doing what:

http://codepen.io/iamjoshellis/pen/waBrQN?editors=001

I'd appreciate any advice/pointers, thanks.

Comment: Please also add the code from your codepen in the question itself (possibly truncated or in minimal format). Outside links can break after some time and when that happens, this question would lose its value to future readers which may have the same problem.

Comment: When you use `.queue`, you should be using [`.dequeue`](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) to inform jQuery that your custom function has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right with the `.stop()` function, however you just used it wrongly. Put the `.stop()` right before the `.animate()`, like this:

```
$('.dog-title').stop().animate({
```

Comment: I actually ended up using a different method with `.fadeIn`  `.fadeOut`  and `.text`, but I think I see the error of my ways now, thanks @DarkAshelin.
  
Pen if it's useful for anyone:  
[http://codepen.io/iamjoshellis/pen/EjaQJZ](http://codepen.io/iamjoshellis/pen/EjaQJZ)